# sforce.one.navigateToFeed TOPICS not working

Tags: salesforce1-app

Thanks for the read!

we have the following method in a visualforce page:

`function redirectToChatterTopic(topicId){
    // Go back to the Account detail page
    if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && sforce && (!!sforce.one) ) {
        // Salesforce1 navigation
        sforce.one.navigateToFeed( topicId, 'TOPICS' );
    }
    else { 
        // Set the window's URL using a Visualforce expression
        window.location.href = '/' + topicId; 
    }
}`

The non-salesforce1 method correctly navigates the the topic page.  When using salesforce1 the navigateToFeed does not correctly redirect to the topic.  Have changed the parameters to {!$User.Id}, 'PEOPLE' and this works fine.  Suspect this is a bug with the navigateToFeed and TOPICS parameter.  Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

response from salesforce --"We received feedback from the R&D teams that the TOPICS type is not supported for the downloadable Salesforce1 applications, and that our documentation team is working on clarifying the limitations to indicate that it will only work within the browser-based Salesforce1 environment. At this time we do not have an estimate as to when this may be implemented in the downloadable app versions for iOS or Android devices. "